# Using VPN configuration which require 'tap' kernel extension on Mac OS Big Sur?

Tags: vpn, kernel-extensions

I use an institutional VPN service by connecting using tunnelblick and the supplied configuration file. Apparently, the configuration file requires tunnelblick to load the "tap" kernel extension which is no longer allowed by macOS Big Sur. The tunnelblick developers have posted that this issue cannot be fixed: https://tunnelblick.net/cBigSur.html. They suggest disabling SIP to use such configs but even that might not be supported in the future. Is there any other client equivalent to tunnelblick that can be used? Is there any other workaround to make this work?

This is the other linked article: https://tunnelblick.net/cTunTapConnections.html

Answer (score 1):

[Viscosity](https://www.sparklabs.com/blog/viscosity-for-mac-windows-version-1-9/) supports TAP on Big Sur.

It costs money though (but it's not that expensive). Hopefully Tunnelblick will go ahead and add it one of these days since Viscosity proved it can be done.